# Is there any script debugging tool for Internet Explorer and Google Chrome?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, firebug

I have tools like firebug and web developer to debug the code with firefox browser is any similar tool we can use with google chrome and internet explorer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Chrome, go to the page menu (the one that looks like a page), then Developer and Developer Tools (Control+Shift+I shortcut)

[image]

For IE, download IE8 and that comes with developer tools. (Tools> Developer Tools) or F12.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome's menu (on a Mac at least):

View > Developer > Developer Tools

Comment: IE8 has a similar tool built-in as well... for earlier versions of IE, you can debug with Visual Studio.

Comment: and how to monitor AJAX requests ? thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) which is nice because it sort of looks and feels like Firebug.

Answer (score 2):

With Internet Explorer you can use Visual Studio to debug code, here some howtos :
http://www.google.com/search?q=using+visual+studio+to+debug+javascript+in+internet+explorer

Visual Studio is not so bad for debugging as it open new tabs while entering in "eval" sections, permitting you to view values and add breakpoints inside them.

Answer (score 2):

For IE6 and IE7 you can download the 'Internet Explorer Developer toolbar", which has the same functionality as the developer tools from IE8. It can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=95E06CBE-4940-4218-B75D-B8856FCED535&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, to debug IE6, I run XP Mode on Win7. The default installed version of IE6 comes with similar developer tools that are activated via a button in the menu bar.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/